# LINQ to Entities equivilent to SQL NOT IN

Tags: t-sql, linq-to-entities

I am having problems converting the following SQL statement to LINQ to Entity.

```
SELECT     Name
FROM       Role
WHERE      ID NOT IN (SELECT Role_ID FROM UserRoleRelation WHERE User_ID = 11)
```

The three tables and their columns are

- User (ID, Uesrname)
- Role (ID, Name)
- UserRoleRelation (ID, User_ID,
  Role_ID)

I tried the following

```
from r in db.Roles
where !db.UserRoleRelations.Any(p => p.User_ID == UserID)
select r
```

Any suggestions?

Mangesh was very close but it pointed me in the right direction.
this is the code that worked.

```
(from r in db.Roles
where !(from y in db.UserRoleRelations where y.User_ID == UserID select y.Role_ID).Contains(r.ID) 
select r);
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
   var result = (from r in db.Roles
                 where !(from y in db.UserRoleRelations
                         where y.User_Id == UserID
                         select y.User_ID).Contains(r.role)
                 select r.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  what you said worked with a slight modification.